# Show that a function is null iff two norms are equivalent

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces, equivalent-metrics

I'm stuck on this question :
$Let~E=C(\left [0,1  \right ],\mathbb{R})~and~let~g\in E.~For~all~f\in E~we~set~N(f)=\left\|fg \right\|_{\infty} $

Where $\left\|\phi\right\|_{\infty}=\sup_{t\in \left [ 0,1 \right ]}\phi(t)$

I've shown that $N$ is a norm iff $g$ doesn't vanish on an intervall of $\left [0,1  \right ]$ and now I have to show that :

$$g(x)\neq 0~for~all~x\in \left [ 0,1 \right ]\iff N~and~\left\|. \right\|_{\infty}~are~equivalent~norms~on~E.$$
For the direct implication, it's not that hard, but for the reciprocal, I'm struggling to figure it out. I'm reasoning by contraposition, supposing that $\exists t_{0}\in \left [ 0,1 \right ]$ such that $g(t_{0}) = 0$ and I'm trying to exhibit a sequence $f_{n}$ such that $\displaystyle \lim_{ n\to \infty}\frac{N(f_{n})}{\left\| f_{n}\right\|_{\infty}}=0~or~\displaystyle \lim_{ n\to \infty}\frac{N(f_{n})}{\left\| f_{n}\right\|_{\infty}}=+\infty$. But all the examples I've tried to find don't work. I'll be grateful if you could help me on this one.

Comment: $g(t_0)$ should be $0$ no?

Comment: Yes totaly, my bad

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Take $f_\epsilon(x)=0$ for $x\not\in (t_0-\epsilon, t_0+\epsilon)$ and $f_\epsilon(x) =1-\left|\frac{x-t_0}{\epsilon} \right|$ for $x\in(t_0-\epsilon, t_0+\epsilon)$.

Comment: So I had to set  $f_{n}(t)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0~for~t\notin \left [ t_{0}-\frac{1}{n},t_{0}+\frac{1}{n}  \right ] \\
1-\left| \frac{t-t_{0}}{\frac{1}{n}}\right|~for~t\in \left [ t_{0}-\frac{1}{n},t_{0}+\frac{1}{n} \right ]
\end{matrix}\right.$ And I guess it is working so thank you very much